# How to manage SQL database using associations and not using keys/ids?

Tags: java, sql

I need some help. 
We get an assignment and the teacher required that we use associations and not using keys/ids. I don't really understand the concept, and how I solve it using SQL database. What I had learned in the database course that we use keys/id to link the tables together. A brief deception of the problem, we have a yacht club, in the club, we can register, delete and edit member. For every member, we can register one or more boat. A member can edit and delete a boat. The problem Should be solved by Model-View separation.

I have solved the problem by creating two tables and link the boat table to the member by memberId. The teacher told me it is not correct to use ID(He said: Basically the UI should add Boats to a Member object, not insert boats in a database with a member id). Can you please give me suggestions on how to solve the issue without using Id.

```
public void createTables() {

    Statement tablesSt;

        try {
            tablesSt = conn.createStatement();
            tablesSt.executeUpdate( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ Boat +
                        " (Boat_ID INT PRIMARY KEY," +
                        " Member_ID INT NOT NULL,"+
                        " Size INT NOT NULL ,"+
                        " Type TEXT NOT NULL ,"+
                        " FOREIGN KEY (Member_ID) REFERENCES " + Member + "(Member_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE) ");

            tablesSt.close();


            tablesSt = conn.createStatement();
            tablesSt.executeUpdate( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ Member +
                        " (Member_ID INT PRIMARY KEY," +
                        " Member_Name TEXT NOT NULL ," +
                        " Personal_Number INT UNIQUE )");
            tablesSt.close();
```

A code from boat class

```
public void newBoat(int memberID, String type, int size ) {
    int BoatId= 0;
    try {

    ResultSet rc=   Control.conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Boat ORDER BY Boat_ID DESC LIMIT 1");
    BoatId =rc.getInt("Boat_ID") +1;

    Statement registerBoat =  Control.conn.createStatement();
              registerBoat.executeUpdate("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Boat VALUES("+BoatId+" , "+memberID+" , '"+size+"', '"+type+"')");
              Control.conn.commit();
              Control.conn.setAutoCommit(false); 

     /*  ResultSet rs2  = Control.conn.createStatement().executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM Boat WHERE Boat_ID ="+ BoatId);
       System.out.println(rs2.getString("type"));*/   // test code to check if the Boat is Succesfully registered 

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: This sounds like your teacher wants you to gain some appreciation for what the "object-relational impedance mismatch" is, if he's insisting you use an SQL based db.Or maybe you're free to use an object database and demonstrate why you needed one in this case

Comment: We are free to use any sort of database. But I choose to use SQL because I am more familiar with it, and he told me it is ok to use SQL.